# How can I get '/path/to/certfile' of a public website for requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using requests to get HTML of a webpage. However, I am running into certificate verification problems. On running the code I get the following error:

> SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Going through other questions I found two solutions. The one that works is by disabling verification through `verify=False` in the function call. However, this is not a safe option.

The other one is to use `verify='/path/to/certfile'`

I am not sure how to get the path to certfile. Through settings in Chromer browser I was taken to a "keychain access" app on mac with various certificates. I exported the certificate "DST Root CA X3" to my working directory and provided the path of that file as `'/path/to/certfile'` value. But that gives me the following error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='rajyasabha.nic.in', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /rsnew/member_site/MemlistElDate.aspx (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(0, 'unknown error (_ssl.c:3622)'),))

python :

```
import requests
url='https://rajyasabha.nic.in/rsnew/member_site/MemlistElDate.aspx'
page=requests.get(url)
```

Is there a different way to get the path to certfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with that site is that the server is not configured correctly to return the intermediate certificate in the certificate chain during TLS handshake. You can check this using the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect rajyasabha.nic.in:443
```

If you scroll down you will see that only depth 0 (the leaf certificate) is sent by the server. This is generally not a problem for web browsers as they cache intermediate certificates, but it is an issue for `requests` as it does not know about it.

The root certificates (`DST Root CA X3` in this case) almost always exist in your operating systems's CA repository. So the certificate we need is this one:

```
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
```

So your best bet is to download the `Let's Encrypt Authority X3` intermediate certificate from the following URL and set that as your `verify` path:

https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

Clarification: You should include both intermediate and the root certificates in your `.pem` file, so it should look like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFjTCCA3WgAwIBAgIRANOxciY0IzLc9AUoUSrsnGowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
...
rUCGwbCUDI0mxadJ3Bz4WxR6fyNpBK2yAinWEsikxqEt
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFazCCA1OgAwIBAgIRAIIQz7DSQONZRGPgu2OCiwAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
...
emyPxgcYxn/eR44/KJ4EBs+lVDR3veyJm+kXQ99b21/+jh5Xos1AnX5iItreGCc=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: I tried: page=requests.get(url, verify='/Users/Path/lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem') but it is returning the same error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with that one but try the second link (signed by ISRG root), and don't forget to append the root (DST) certificate at the end of the file because when you use `verify=` it will not ask your operating system for the root certificate anymore. You have to supply both manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working perfectly now. So, I assume that is the solution in future whenever I come across this kind of problem.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. It shouldn't happen very often as usually web servers are configured to provide the intermediate certificate together with the leaf certificate.

Comment: If I may ask another related question. It happened again and this time the two certificates are DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA and GeoTrust EV RSA CA 2018. Both are on this [page](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm). I tried doing the same thing as last time but when I open the certificate in a text editor I get garbled text. Is there a way to add on the intermediate certificate to the root certificate?

Comment: If they look like garbage they are probably in a binary (DER, PKCS#12) format. Use the openssl command line, or an online converter such as [this one](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html) to convert it to the PEM format.

Comment: Once again it worked like a charm. I am new to all this and I really appreciate your help.